# This is what I see when i start

Tags: command-line, dual-boot, bash

```
GNU GRUB version 2.04 

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word,
TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists
possible device or file completions.

grub> _
```

Comment: Welcome. We will need more information in order to help you. Are you trying to install dual boot and if so, what version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Comment: well i already installed this version Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS alongside with  windows 10 . everything was fine until i had to shut down my laptop and when it open i had that massage

Answer (score 1):

The workaround solution for this problem can be categorized depending if your system is UEFI or not.

***Prerequisites:***

- Create a Live USB using the Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS image file you installed on your system.
- Ensure that your internet connection is stable, as any hiccup can prove fatal

Now, follow these steps:

- Boot into your Live USB
- Run the command `sudo fdisk -l` to identify if your system uses EFI or BIOS
- Note down the partition where EFI is installed (if it is), and the partition where the root is installed

***For UEFI Systems:***

- Mount the root using the command: `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`

DO NOT FORGET to Replace `/dev/sda2/` with your root partition details

- Mount EFI too (if its present) using the command: `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi`
- Reinstall grub using the command:`sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot --bootloader-id=ubuntu  --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/mnt/boot/efi`
- Restart your system using: `shutdown -r now`

***For Non-EFI systems:***

- Mount the root partition using: `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`
  DO NOT FORGET to Replace `/dev/sda2/` with your root partition details
- Reinstall grub using: `sudo grub-install /dev/sd2`
- Reboot your system & you should no longer see this error.

***Alternative workaround: Using Boot Repair***

- Plug in your Live USB and boot into the session
- Execute these 3 commands one-by-one to install Boot Repair:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install boot-repair`

- Repair boot with Boot Repair: `boot-repair &`

Follow the instructions from here & execute commands (if you're asked to do so). Once you complete, your system should boot normally.

Let us know if these steps work for you or not. If they do, please mark this answer as the "solution" to keep the forum clean.

Information source: [ItsFOSS](https://itsfoss.com/fix-minimal-bash-line-editing-supported-grub-error-linux/)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Can you boot into Windows? If so please try the following

1. Boot into Windows and goto the settings and **disable "Fast Startup"**. Exit Windows.
2. Then boot into the UEFI/BIOS and as indicated above, make sure you are in **UEFI** mode and Secure Boot is **disabled**.

If you can't boot into Windows, try the Boot Repair utility with a Live USB in the answer above and then goto step 1.

You should also state the make and model of your laptop as some machines have extra steps that have to be completed.